# Change class and text on jQuery AJAX success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link:

```
<a href="#" class="confirmed" data-ev="1">
  <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
  <span class="text-warning">confirm this!</span>
</a>
```

I tried everything in comment sections in this code:

```
$(".confirmed").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var that  = this;
   $.ajax({
    url: '/confirmed/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      event_type: $(that).data('ev')
    },
        success: function(result) {
          $(that).data('ev',"10");
          // here I want to change the class of i tag to "icon-ok"
          // and span.class to "text-success"
          // and span.text to "confirmed"
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the parent `<a>` element already. You just need to do a [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(that).find('i').addClass('icon-ok');
$(that).find('span').text('blah');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class with [`jQuery.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Remove class with [`jQuery.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Set text content with [`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

This are very simple jQuery tasks, and you would easily have found them using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+add+class). That is also why my post does not contain any code.

Comment: my anchors are multi, so i couldnt change on "clicked", of course i searched and google.

Comment: `$(that).find('i').addClass('whatever-dude');` to find the `i`-tag within.

Comment: thanks, it is Ok now, Josh solved before you, sorry for my dummy question.